# fail to install oracle Weblogic

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I have download  the Generic version of the installer (fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar).
and try use cmd: java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar for install.
and use two differnet java version(jdk11 and jdk18) to install but it still showed same error. could you help me to solve it:

> 

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerSpi: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:673)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1233)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1265)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1300)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1385)
        at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerSpi.getDataHandlerProvider(DataHandlerSpi.java:80)
        at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.getDataHandlerProvider(DaoHelper.java:122)
        at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.parse(DaoHelper.java:161)
        at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.getRootWrapper(DaoHelper.java:307)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getOptionsInfoDao(OptionsParser.java:474)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.parseOptionsDao(OptionsParser.java:183)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.<init>(OptionsParser.java:130)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getInstance(OptionsParser.java:117)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.OUIOptions.<init>(OUIOptions.java:53)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputsImpl.<init>(InputsImpl.java:50)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputsImpl.<clinit>(InputsImpl.java:34)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.helpers.InputHandler.getInputs(InputHandler.java:29)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.processCommandLineArgs(Launcher.java:2561)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:3197)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:3187)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:660)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:657)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:668)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: This is probably off-topic for this site. [WLS 12c is certified for JDK8](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES583); and see [the certification matrix](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/fusion-middleware/documentation/fmw-1221certmatrix-2739738.xlsx). You can't use JDK 9 or later.  Why do you want to use such an old version though?

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic Server 12.1.3 is not supported with JDK 11 or 18. You must use JDK 7 or 8 only.